# How to individually select < li > and then use modulus to select the odd ones

Tags: javascript, dom, modulus

ALright so I got a homework from my teacher to first select every individual < li > and then use modulus to select only the odd ones and change their color.
And I have to say that I am completely stumped.

I have tried selecting using child nodes:
var `listaOne = document.getElementById ("lista1").childNodes[0];`

HTML

```
<ul id="lista1">
                <li>List item 1</li>
                <li>List item 2</li>
                <li>List item 3</li>
                <li>List item 4</li>
                <li>List item 5</li>
            </ul>
```

JS

```
    listaOne = document.getElementById ("lista1").childNodes[0];
listaTwo = document.getElementById ("lista1").childNodes[1];
listaThree = document.getElementById ("lista1").childNodes[2];
listaFour = document.getElementById ("lista1").childNodes[3];
listaFive = document.getElementById ("lista1").childNodes[4];
```

I want to be able to choose an < li > individually

Comment: It's `.childNodes` (plural) not `.childNode` (singular) -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Comment: Welcome to SO! Any time in code you find yourself doing `thing1`, `thing2`...`thingN`. Please don't type that all out--use an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and a [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration). Use the above link and the mod operator when iterating through the collection to determine parity (`n % 2 === 0`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get the array of `li`.

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll('#lista1 li');
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].style.color = 'blue';
}

var oddLis = document.querySelectorAll('#lista1 li:nth-child(odd)');
for (var i = 0; i < oddLis.length; i++) {
  oddLis[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<ul id="lista1">
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
    <li>List item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: _"and then **use modulus** to select only the odd ones"_

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all `li` elements. Then filter the odd ones using the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) provided by [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). Then you have yourself an array of `li` elements.

Here, I'm using the spread operator to convert the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) into an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

```js
const lis = [...document.querySelectorAll('#lista1 > li')];

lis.filter((li, i) => i % 2).forEach(li => li.style.color = 'red');
```

```html
<ul id="lista1">
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
  <li>List item 4</li>
  <li>List item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or even better as Samuel used it, a nice CSS selector coupled with the native [`NodeList#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach): `document.querySelectorAll('#lista1 li:nth-child(even)').forEach(li => li.style.color = 'red');`

Comment: _"and then **use modulus** to select only the odd ones"_

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to do it, a forEach loop would package up the code necessary should you select every element.

```
var nodeList = document.getElementById('parent').childNodes;

nodeList.forEach((node, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        // code for evens here
    } else {
        // code for odds here
    }
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList